# Notebook (.nb) → Jupyter (.ipynb) conversion without Mathematica?

Tags: conversion, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to convert Mathematica Notebook files (.nb) to Jupyter files (.ipynb) without using Mathematica?
Is there a free online utility or other piece of software that can do this?

Comment: This might be better asked on Stack Overflow? Unless you don't mind a solution that uses the free Wolfram Engine. Otherwise I think people might prefer being able to use the Mathematica language.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I assumed that OP meant creating Jupyter notebooks that still contain WL code and would be used with the free wolfram engine.

Comment: Jupyter notebooks are just JSON files, so at least grabbing the input cell text and placing that in an ipynb should be quite feasible, and not too hard. Converting other stuff is (much) more trouble, but still feasible. I don't have time for this, but if anyone is willing to spend and afternoon or two, it should be possible to do this.

Comment: Any updates with this? I'm trying to do the same thing. I have a bunch of old Mathematica notebooks that I want to use with Jupyter + Wolfram engine.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack No.